# Set text-align to right every second row of a table

Tags: css, css-tables

I want to create a table, where first row will have grey background and second row will have text-align set to right and this will be repeated.

```
Grey background
Right
Grey bg
Right
...
```

I already made the grey row, but how to make the right align every second row? I have even tried making right align on the grey row with this code:

```
.p-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align:right;
}
```

But the text align doesn't change.

Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: Can we see your HTML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to put the text-align on your `<td>` element rather than the row:

```
.p-table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.p-table tr:nth-child(odd) td {
  text-align:right;
}
```

`td` or whatever element actually contains your text

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
table tr:nth-child(odd){
   background-color: grey
}
table tr:nth-child(even){
   text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a `nth-child(even)` CSS selector, so you just need a `nth-child(odd)` selector. The `nth-child(even)` selector will control the text alignment, while `nth-child(odd)` will control the background color. Here's some example code:

```
li:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: grey
}
li:nth-child(even) {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Without seeing your HTML code, I can't give you the exact CSS that will match your HTML, so you'll have to adapt the above code with your HTML.